# monthly repeated alarm in alarmmanager

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want that a monthly reminder can be set in my application. For example you choose "1." then the reminder should always be called at the 1st of each month.

How can I do this with AlarmManager and setrepeating()? The problem is that there are months which have 29, 30 and 31 days. So I cannot use a fixed repeating interval in alarmmanager's setrepeating(), right?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use repeating alarms. Use alarm to occur once, and reschedule the alarm when it occurs.

Comment: See this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340096/android-alarm-setting-with-specific-date

Comment: i think this answer would help
[check this link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645749/android-repeating-alarm-should-repeat-on-monthly-basis-and-on-same-day-for-each/26646069#26646069