# android repeating alarm, should repeat on monthly basis and on same day for each month so on after its set

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

alarm should repeat on monthly basis, once a month on same date for each month so on after its set
like if i place alarm on october 31, then it should repeat on 31 of months having 31 days, as we don't have same number of days for each month 
I'am having trouble with figuring out the interval of this alarm, please help me how to figure out what this INTERVAL_Value has to be or how to handle it in another way

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_Value, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568233/how-to-implement-yearly-and-monthly-repeating-alarms) helps.

Comment: i figured it out another way going to post that as an anwer, i think this is it this could work

Answer (score 1):

we can recieve currentMonth value from source and it is an integer

```
if (currentMonth == Calendar.JANUARY || currentMonth == Calendar.MARCH || currentMonth == Calendar.MAY || currentMonth == Calendar.JULY 
            || currentMonth == Calendar.AUGUST || currentMonth == Calendar.OCTOBER || currentMonth == Calendar.DECEMBER){
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 31, alarmIntent);
    }
    if (currentMonth == Calendar.APRIL || currentMonth == Calendar.JUNE || currentMonth == Calendar.SEPTEMBER 
            || currentMonth == Calendar.NOVEMBER){
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 30, alarmIntent);
        }


    if  (currentMonth == Calendar.FEBRUARY){//for feburary month)
        GregorianCalendar cal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();    
            if(cal.isLeapYear(year)){//for leap year feburary month  
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 29, alarmIntent);
            }
            else{ //for non leap year feburary month
                alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 28, alarmIntent);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`.
This gives you the maximum date for each month irrespective of the month.